# Wenn das Produkt Schuhe (sind/ist),

Tags: verb

Sagt man,

> Wenn das Produkt Schuhe sind, ...

oder

> Wenn das Produkt Schuhe ist, ...

?

Für mich klingt es logisch, wenn ich sage *Wenn das Produkt Schuhe sind* aber ich denke, dass sich das Verb auf das Wort *Produkt* bezieht und nicht auf *Schuhe*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ja, der Plural "gewinnt" in dem Fall immer.

> Wenn das Produkt Schuhe sind, ...

https://www.deutschplus.net/pages/Schwierigkeiten_bei_der_Kongruenz/Schwierigkeiten-bei-der-Kongruenz-10

Comment: Interesting, in English it would depend on context/emphasis. If you were talking about different products and one of them was shoes, then "If the product is shoes." If you were talking about shoes and where they might come from then it would be "If shoes are the product."

Answer (score 2):

> Wenn das Produkt Schuhe sind, ...

Das ist richtig.

---

> Das Produkt ist toll.

> Schuhe sind das Produkt.

> Der Baum ist das Produkt.

> In diesem Bach sind (gibt es) viele Fische.